# Bullets in a Xaml Tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml

Everything is in the title. I'd like to be able to add some bullet list in a Tooltip but so far haven't found any simple way.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try the answer has given by me?

Comment: cf. my comments on your answer

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the `BulletDecorator` as part of the `ToolTip`. Example:

```
      <ToolTip>
        <BulletDecorator>
          <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Fill="Blue"/>
          </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
          <TextBlock>Text with a bullet!</TextBlock>
        </BulletDecorator>
      </ToolTip>
```

For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.bulletdecorator(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems the best approach so far and working well! Still, it seems I have to add some decorator per every single bullet I have? Any tips to not declare one each time?

Comment: Yeah, you would have to add one each time. You could wrap it in an ItemsPanel, and bind it using a collection of strings. Inside the ItemsPanel datatemplate, you can just specify only one BulletDecorator.

Answer (score 0):

you must have a custom tooltip for this

a nice blog example
http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/custom-tooltip-and-popup.html

microsoft info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745107.aspx

just put somekind of rich textbox or listbox in the content...

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:
Why don't use [unicode characters](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) (0x2981 for example) and `\r\n` for lie breaks?

Answer (score -1):

I got it displaying correctly with the following:

```
<ListView
        x:Name="listView"
        Margin="0,-5,0,0"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        HeightRequest="50"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TradingHoursList}"
        SeparatorColor="Transparent">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="&#x2022;"/>
                    <Label
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            FontAttributes="Italic"
                            FontFamily="Arial Black"
                            FontSize="15"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Text="{Binding}"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```