# How do I create a bulleted list in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I just need a simple list of items with bullets preceding them.  How can I do this?  I can't find any control that does this  I can use grids and such to accomplish this, but it seems like so much work for something so simple

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just insert the bullet character directly into your XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="• Item 1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="• Item 2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You can also use the [Hex HTML entity](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm):

```
<TextBlock>&#x2022; Item 1</TextBlock>
```

If the items come from a viewmodel / binding, then use an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='• {0}'}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

<sub>Footnote: Not relevant to Silverlight/Windows Phone, but WPF has [BulletDecorator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.bulletdecorator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19699590/1001985).</sub>

Comment: where are these bullet characters?  copied from character map? I found one in Symbol set but its much smaller than yours

Comment: @erotavlas yes, copied.  You can also use the hex Unicode character, like `<TextBlock>&#x2022; Item 1</TextBlock>`.

Answer (score 1):

I used a stackpanel with bulletdecorators to show a bullet list:

```
<StackPanel>
  <BulletDecorator>
    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
      <Rectangle Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Gray" />
    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
    <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0">Step 1: test</TextBlock>
  </BulletDecorator>
  <BulletDecorator>
    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
      <Rectangle Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Gray" />
    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
    <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0">Step 2: test</TextBlock>
  </BulletDecorator>
</StackPanel>
```